# reading in columns from csv file

Tags: c++, csv

Im trying to edit some code that reads in columns from a txt file to be able to read in from a csv file. The main problem I'm having is that the data in the txt files was stored as: 1 2 3 4. In the csv files the data looks like: "1","2","3","4". I'll include my current code (works for txt) below. Is it easier to edit my current code or just start over?

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("filepath");
char temp[200];
while(!fin.eof())
   {
    fin.getline(temp,200);
    if(sscanf(temp,"%f %f %f %*f\n",&var1,&var2,&var3)!=3)
        {
        continue;
        }
   printf("%f %f %f \n",var1,var2,var3);
   }
```

Comment: You could learn a lot from *all* the other CSV posts on StackOverflow, by searching for "c++ read csv".

Comment: yeah, I spent a half hour reading through them but couldn't find anything that addressed my exact problem. I don't doubt that it exists somewhere though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't have to change your code. Change your scanf function to

```
    if(sscanf(temp, "\"%f\", \"%f\", \"%f\", \"%*f\"\n",,&var1,&var2,&var3)!=3)
```

to match the new format and it should work.